# How to expand cell height and change layout after button clicked in collection view?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm wondering how to do something like this for my collection view cell. Below 1st picture shows there is nothing between date time section and buttons.

[image]

Then after you press heart button, the cell expand height and show a new section which displays amount of hearts.
[image]

I'm sure it is not simple like hidden/unhidden. I'm just wondering does anyone have a clue how to achieve something similar? Is there a way that we can add 2 sets of layouts (one likes picture 1 and one likes picture 2) and switch between each one based on button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as hidden/unhidden. For instance you can use `UIStackView` to achieve this effect, and thanks to autolayout and self-sizing table view cells, everything works like a charm:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

You can follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/grand-parade/animating-uitableviewcell-size-and-text-change-using-auto-layout-and-automatic-dimension-a64bf8cb01b2